# How can I make excel divide a < value by another real value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a large environmental data set with < values.  I need to divide these less than values by 2.  For example, I want a value of < 20 to report a value of 10.  I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test to see if the `<` is present and do your math accordingly.

Here is one of many possible solutions:

`=IFERROR(REPLACE(A1,FIND("<",A1),1,"+")/2,A1)`